# String transformation

Tags: algorithms

> There are $n$ light bulbs place in circle and colored with Red, Green,
>   Blue. After 1 second, from left to right, 2 consecutive bulbs which
>   have different color will both change to extant color. After $k$
>   second, how the circle of bulbs will look like ?

For example:

After $1$ second, $BRR$ changed to $RBR$

$BRR \to GGR \to GBB \to RBR \to GGR \to...$

I can solve this problem by a computer (simulate how it change second by second), but I don't know what is the most efficient algorithm(s) (is it exist ?), please help me, thanks.

Comment: (1) In your notation are the first and last considered adjacent? (2) Is there a rule about which two different adjacents to change at each step? (3) In your first example the BR of BRR each switched to its opposite, while in the second one, differing adjacent pairs got changed to a third color. Which is it?

Comment: 1) yes. 2) from left to right, 1st and 2nd, 2nd and 3rd..., n-1 and nth, nth and 1st. 3) GR changed to BB

Comment: So once you reach nth and 1st, you continue again with 1st and 2nd, etc, and you want to know what the initial string looks like after k steps, given any initial string and any k>0? I would be surprised if there were a way to do this except by a program (i.e. an algorithm), and also cannot see how a more efficient way could do it than actually running through the swaps. [One more question (just to be sure): when encountering two adjacents which are the same, one just skips over that and proceeds to the next?]

Comment: Yes, just skip to the next.

Comment: You might find useful information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton

Comment: Your algorithm can use the fact that there will be a cycle. The problem seems to general to tell more

Comment: I don't agree with "After 1 second, BRR changed to RBR". I believe that you mean "After 1 second, BRR changed to GGR", as in your next line.

Comment: @CalvinLin: My mean is that how it changed step by step, not second by second. After $1 / length(BRR)$ second it changed to $GGR$

Comment: Ah I see. The third result is RBR. Thanks.

Comment: What is the origin of this problem? The wording suggests it's a problem from some programming competition -- and knowing things like limits on the length of the string or number of seconds can provide very good hints about the algorithm we're looking for.

Comment: $n \le 10000$, $1 ≤ k ≤ 30000$ original problem not in English, the forum posted this don't have solution / source where does it take from

Comment: Could you specify the starting condition somewhat more precise? What is the starting condition, if initially all n bulbs have the same color?

Comment: What would BBBGRGBBB change to in the next step?

Comment: @Henry: If I understand the rules correctly: $\mathbf{BB}BGRGBBB$ $\to$ $\color{red}{B}\mathbf{\color{red}{B}B}GRGBBB$ $\to$ $B\color{red}{B}\mathbf{\color{red}{B}G}RGBBB$ $\to$ $BB\color{red}{R}\mathbf{\color{red}{R}R}GBBB$ $\to$ $BBR\color{red}{R}\mathbf{\color{red}{R}G}BBB$ $\to$ $BBRR\color{red}{B}\mathbf{\color{red}{B}B}BB$ $\to$ $BBRRB\color{red}{B}\mathbf{\color{red}{B}B}B$ $\to$ $BBRRBB\color{red}{B}\mathbf{\color{red}{B}B}$ $\to$ $\mathbf{B}BRRBBB\color{red}{B\mathbf{B}}$ $\to$ $\color{red}{B}BRRBBBB\color{red}{B}$.

Comment: The community should refuse to deal with this question any further before the rules of the game are not spelled out completely and clearly in the body of the question.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Why do you think this question is unclear ?

Answer (score 1):

If we interpret our colours as ternary digits, we can come up with a mechanism for handling this fairly easily.

Let's consider pairs of digits, such as 00 or 12. For notation, we will let the first digit be $a$ and the second digit be $b$, so the pair is $ab$. Now, suppose we let $c=2(a+b)\pmod3$. Then here is the table of possible pairs:

```
00 -> 0
01 -> 2
02 -> 1
10 -> 2
11 -> 1
12 -> 0
20 -> 1
21 -> 0
22 -> 2
```

Therefore, you replace both digits with $2(a+b)\pmod3$. It does not matter which digit is assigned to which colour.

Now, if we look at what happens with slightly longer runs, we can have some further insight into the way that the system evolves. For three digits (that is, two steps), with a starting value of $abc$, we find (working in mod 3) that the first digit becomes $2(a+b)$, and then the second and third digits become $2(2(a+b)+c) = a+b+2c$. For four digits (three steps), with $d$ for the initial fourth digit, the third and fourth digits become $2(a+b+2c+d)=c+2(a+b+d)$. For five (adding $e$), we get $2(c+2(a+b+d)+e)=a+b+d+2(c+e)$.

This pattern is difficult to simplify... unless we make a nice choice for the arbitrary assignment of colours. If we choose to let the colour of the first light be assigned $a=0$ as its digit, then it is easy to see that the first light will take the value $2b$, the second will be $b+2c$, the third will be $2b+c+2d$, the fourth will be $b+2c+d+2e$, and so on. The pattern becomes quite clear with this choice. Specifically, if we let $a_i$ be the $i$th initial digit ($a_1=0$), and $b_i$ be the $i$th resulting digit, then for a run of $k<n$, we have, for the first $k$ digits,

$$
b_j=\sum_{i=1}^{j} 2^{i+j+1}a_{i+1} \mod 3
$$
and $b_{k+1}=b_k$, of course. That being said, implementing this as an algorithm is best done by utilising the evaluation process of $b_j=\text{mod}(2(b_{j-1}+a_j),3)$, with the wrap-around between lights $n$ and $1$ being handled by simply taking the appropriate modulo on the index $j$. This then simply requires an initial sweep converting the colours to appropriate digits (assign the first light's colour as $0$, then choose the other two however you see fit from there), and conversion back at the end with another sweep.